# How do I configure an angular2 Injectable

Tags: angular

In AngularJS I can configure a service on the Application level by using

```
myApp.config(function(unicornLauncherProvider) {

});
```

Reference:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

What is the angular2 equivalent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular2 supports constructor-based dependency injection. To be able to inject something you need to specify its associated provider when bootstrapping the application or within the `providers` attribute of components.

Here is a sample:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ UnicornLauncher ]);
```

or

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ UnicornLauncher ]
})
```

then you can specify the type into the constructor parameter:

```
constructor(private launcher:UnicornLauncher) {
}
```

Note that you need a decorator around the corresponding class like `Component` or `Injectable`.

**Edit**

If you want to "configure" a provider, you could leverage the `provide` function with `useFactory`:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  provide(UnicornLauncher, { useFactory: () => {
    let ul = new UnicornLauncher();
    // configure
    return ul;
  })
]);
```

Comment: Thanks but this not answer my question: How do I configure the unicornLauncher. (the example on angularjs 1 guide show how you can change the useTinfoilShielding.

Comment: Yes sorry ;-) I updated my answer but there is no config phase in Angular2... You could leverage the `provide` function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking on how to use providers to configure how your service will be injected, is that right?

If so, let's take what Thierry posted as an example.

**Providers:**
[UnicornLauncher] is just a cleaner way to tell angular how to instantiate a service. 
This is what angular understands:

```js
[new Provider(UnicornLauncher, {useClass: UnicornLauncher})]
```

Suppose you want to use a different class whenever UnicornLauncher is injected:

```js
[new Provider(UnicornLauncher, {useClass: UnicornLauncherCustom})]
```

There are many ways to configure your own provider. I suggest you take a look at the angular documentation.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html?The%20Provider%20class%20and%20provide%20function#!#providers

Regards,